# Suma de arrays en Java

Tags: java, eclipse

Quería implementar la siguiente función de Python para sumar arrays en Java. Tengo varias dudas con el bucle. Trabajando en Eclipse cuando trato de realizar el bucle `for i in range(len(numbers1), len(numbers2)):` lo he implementado de la siguiente forma `for (; i < number1.length && i < number2.length; i++)`. He puesto el `;` porque me indicaba que el bucle precisa de una estructura formada por 3 "partes". De igual modo, para implementar la sentencia `elif` me pedía cerrar la estructura previa, el `if`y el `for`con las debidas `}`

**Código en Python:**

```
def sum_lists(numbers1, numbers2):

  result = [0 for i in range(max(len(numbers1), len(numbers2)))]

  for i in range(min(len(numbers1), len(numbers2))):
    result[i] = numbers1[i] + numbers2[i]
  if len(numbers1) > len(numbers2):
    for i in range(len(numbers2), len(numbers1)):
      result[i] = numbers1[i]
  elif len(numbers1) < len(numbers2):
    for i in range(len(numbers1), len(numbers2)):
      result[i] = numbers2[i]
  return result
```

**Código en Java:**

```
public static int[] sumLists(int[] number1, int[] number2) {

        int[] result = new int [Math.max(number1.length, number2.length)];

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(number1.length, number2.length); i++) {
            result[i] = number1[i] + number2[i];
        if (number1.length > number2.length) {
            for (; i < number2.length && i < number1.length; i++) {
                result[i] = number1[i];         // Duda

        }}else if (number1.length < number2.length) {
                for (; i < number1.length && i < number2.length; i++) {   // Duda
                    result[i] = number2[i];
                }
            }
        }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los condicionales no deben estar dentro del `for`, se deben ejecutar después para completar el array con los elementos sobrantes si uno de ellos es mayor, exactamente como ocurre en la implementación de Python.

Si los colocas dentro se ejecutaran en cada iteración del for. Además, el rango de índices en los condicionales debe ser:

- **Si numbers1 > numbers2** -> desde `numbers2.length` hasta `numbers1.length - 1`

  Equivalente a `range(len(numbers2), len(numbers1))` en Python.
- **Si numbers1 < numbers2** -> desde `numbers1.length` hasta `numbers2.length - 1`

  Equivalente a `range(len(numbers1), len(numbers2))` en Python.

---

```
public static int[] sumLists(int[] number1, int[] number2) {

    int[] result = new int [Math.max(number1.length, number2.length)];

    for (int i=0; i < Math.min(number1.length, number2.length); i++) {
        result[i] = number1[i] + number2[i];
    }
    if (number1.length > number2.length) {
        for (int i = number2.length; i < number1.length; i++) {
            result[i] = number1[i];
        }
    }
    else if (number1.length < number2.length) {
        for (int i = number1.length; i < number2.length; i++) {
            result[i] = number2[i];
        }
    }
return result;
}
```

Se pueden eliminar casi todas las llaves si lo deseas en este caso, dado que solo hay un estamento debajo de cada `for` o condicional, pero generalmente las convenciones de estilo no lo recomiendan, es más fácil cometer errores (la identación aquí es meramente visual, no como en Python) y dificulta el mantenimiento:

```
public static int[] sumLists(int[] number1, int[] number2) {

    int[] result = new int [Math.max(number1.length, number2.length)];

    for (int i=0; i < Math.min(number1.length, number2.length); i++)
        result[i] = number1[i] + number2[i];
    if (number1.length > number2.length)
        for (int i = number2.length; i < number1.length; i++)
            result[i] = number1[i];
    else if (number1.length < number2.length)
        for (int i = number1.length; i < number2.length; i++)
            result[i] = number2[i];

return result;
}
```

Por cierto, una forma mucho más simple y eficiente de hacer ésto en Python, además con un número indeterminado de listas es usar `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def sum_lists(*listas):
    return [sum(items) for items in zip_longest(*listas,fillvalue=0)]
```

> ```
> >>> numbers1= [1, 2, 3]
> >>> numbers2 = [4, 5]
> >>> sum_lists(numbers1, numbers2)
> [5, 7, 3]
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Tenía una pequeña curiosidad, cuando mencionas "generalmente las convenciones de estilo no lo recomiendan, es más fácil cometer errores (la identación aquí es meramente visual, no como en Python) y dificulta el mantenimiento:" a que se debe la dificultad de dicho mantenimiento. Gracias nuevamente

Comment: Básicamente, si en un futuro se tienen que agregar al bloque líneas, hay que crear las llaves y envolverlo todo, si se olvida agregar las llaves esas lineas se ejecutarán fuera del bloque lo que puede terminar en excepciones o en bugs silentes. Parece una tontería en un código de pocas lineas como éste pero es más fácil de lo que parece cometer el error que comento, y si no se comete hay que preocuparse de agregar las llaves, mientras que si están desde el inicio con agregar la linea basta. Luego se pueden agregar otras razones puramente de estéticas, pero lo anterior creo que es lo esencial.

Answer (score 1):

El primer problema está en que no debes meterlo todo en el primer for. Otro problema lo tienes en la condición de parada. El for debería parar cuando se llegue a la longitud del array mayor, en tu caso esto no pasa. Aqui tienes la correción:

```
public static int[] sumLists(int[] number1, int[] number2) {

        int[] result = new int [Math.max(number1.length, number2.length)];

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(number1.length, number2.length); i++) {
            result[i] = number1[i] + number2[i];
        }
        if (number1.length > number2.length) {
            for (int j = number2.length ; j < number1.length; j++) {
                result[i] = number1[i]; 
            }
        }else if (number2.length > number1.length) {
             for (int j = number1.length ; j < number2.length; j++) {  
                result[i] = number2[i];
             }
        }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba una lógica distinta:

```
public static int[] sumLists(int[] number1, int[] number2) {

int[] result = new int [Math.max(number1.length, number2.length)];
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(number1.length, number2.length); i++) {
  result[i] = number1[i] + number2[i];
  if (!(i<Math.min(number1.length, number2.length)-1) && number1.length>number2.length)
    for(int j=i+1;i<number1.length;j++)
      result[j] = number1[j];
  else if (!(i<Math.min(number1.length, number2.length)-1) && number1.length<number2.length)
    for(int j=i+1;i<number2.length;j++)
      result[j] = number2[j];
}
return result;
```

Los compañeros muestran otras lógicas distintas, con las continuaciones del result según qué otro array es mayor fuera del primer for. De cualquier manera, los bucles for no pueden tener el formato que propones, y por lo tanto te tienes que buscar otra lógica de ejecutarlo distinta, como las propuestas por los contertulios o la aquí expuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerla más corta y sin tantos `if`s simplemente asignando a referencias nuevas los arreglos de menor y mayor longitud según corresponda, y si son del mismo tamaño no afecta el comportamiento. Además al usar nombres más claros puedes entenderlo mejor:

```
public static int[] sumLists(int[] number1, int[] number2) {
    int[] smaller = (number1.length < number2.length) ? number1 : number2;
    int[] bigger = (number1.length < number2.length) ? number2 : number1;

    int[] result = new int[bigger.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < bigger.length; i++)
        result[i] = (i < smaller.length) ? smaller[i] + bigger[i] : bigger[i];

    return result;
}
```